# G-invariant measure class

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

I'm reading Nicolas Monod's book *Continuous Bounded Cohomology of Locally Compact Group*. I don't understand the meaning of **G-invariant measure class** in Definition 2.1.1. 
[image]
Does it mean $\mu(A)=\mu(gA),$for all Borel set $A$ and $g\in G$? But the follwing Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{dg^{-1}\mu}{d\mu}$ will be meaningless.
So dose it mean $g\mu<<\mu$ and $\mu <<g\mu$ $ \forall g\in G$ where $g\mu(A)=\mu(gA)$?